# Using two different frameworks on a single domain (Oracle Weblogic / Django)

Tags: python, django, oracle, apache, weblogic

Suppose my company has a site at https://example.com, and it is powered by an older version of Oracle Weblogic. The company wants to eventually transition the site to a Django framework, but wants to do it piecemeal.

Specifically, it wants to maintain the original site on the old framework, but wants set up a subfolder like https://example.com/newurl/ (or, alternatively, a subdomain like https://newurl.example.com) which will contain a Django project with new features etc., and any subdirectories within this new url will likewise consist of Django apps only.

My question is, is it possible to contain both frameworks on the same domain in this manner, and if so how one would go about it using Apache? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, sure it's possible. Try [reverse proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy) software, such as:

- [Nginx Proxy](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/)
- [HaProxy](http://www.haproxy.org/)
- [Varnish Cache](https://varnish-cache.org/)

> **reverse proxy** is a type of [proxy server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server) that retrieves resources on behalf of a [client](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client_(computing)) from one or more [servers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_(computing)). These resources are then returned to the client, appearing as if they originated from the proxy server itself.[[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy#cite_note-apache-forward-reverse-1) Unlike a [forward proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_proxy), which is an intermediary for its associated clients to contact any server, a reverse proxy is an intermediary for its associated servers to be contacted by any client. In other words, a *proxy* acts on behalf of the client(s), while a *reverse-proxy* acts on behalf of the server(s). ()
>   [image]

## Nginx reverse proxy sample config

```
server {
  listen 80;

  server_name example.com;

  location ~ /newurl {
    proxy_pass http://django-server;
  }

  location ~ /oldurl {
    proxy_pass http://oracle-weblogic-server;
  }
}
```

## HaProxy reverse proxy sample config

```
frontend http_frontend
bind *:80
mode http
option httpclose
acl is_newurl hdr_end(host) -i newurl
use_backend django if is_newurl
acl is_oldurl hdr_end(host) -i oldurl
use_backend oracle if is_oldurl

backend django
mode http
cookie SERVERID insert indirect nocache
server django django-server:80 check cookie django

backend oracle
mode http
cookie SERVERID insert indirect nocache
server oracle oracle-weblogic-server:80 check cookie oracle
```